# How to delete this element of html?

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm cleaning the html of this [url](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/aimer). In particular, I want to remove `<input checked="" class="selectorOpernerBig" id="default" name="selectorOpernerBig" type="radio">`. Its full xpath is `/html/body/div/div[1]/div/input`. Its structure is

[image]

I tried to remove with

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/aimer'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers = headers).content, 'html.parser')
    
remove = soup.find_all('input', {'checked' : ''})  
for match in remove:
    match.decompose()    

entry_name = soup.h2.text
content = ''.join(map(str, soup.select_one('.res_cell_center').contents))
```

Sadly, it removes anything in `<div class="page" == $0` and `</div>`. Could you please elaborate on this issue and how to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with BeautifulSoup to:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = '''
<div class="page"><input type="radio" id="default" class="selectorOpernerBig" name="selectorOpernerBig" checked=""/><label for="default" class="shadow_layer"> </label><label for="default" class="menuPanelCloseButton icon-times icon-2x"> </label></div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

remove = soup.find_all('input', {'checked': ''})
for r in remove:
    r.extract()

print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<div class="page">
 <label class="shadow_layer" for="default">
 </label>
 <label class="menuPanelCloseButton icon-times icon-2x" for="default">
 </label>
</div>
```

If the script already have BeautifulSoup it is better to continue to use BeautifulSoup then import more libs.

Comment: I have similar commands, for example `for match in soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'example-info'}): ` and `for match in soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'share-overlay'}): `. Is it possible to merge them into one command?

Comment: @LAD I can not answer straight into the air for a specific case. But I would probably have them separated to make it easier to troubleshoot any problems.

Comment: Please see my full question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63114903/how-to-combine-several-similar-commands-using-for-match-in-soup-find-all). I'm sorry for bothering you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req
html = '''
<div class="page"><input type="radio" id="default" class="selectorOpernerBig" name="selectorOpernerBig" checked=""/><label for="default" class="shadow_layer"> </label><label for="default" class="menuPanelCloseButton icon-times icon-2x"> </label></div>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
remove = doc.select('input#default')
if remove: remove.repleaceSelf('')
print (doc.html)
```

Result:

```
<div class="page"><label for="default" class="shadow_layer"> </label><label for="default" class="menuPanelCloseButton icon-times icon-2x"> </label></div>
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

Comment: If you don't mind, please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63112871/why-does-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-contents-occur-with-only-one).

Comment: @LAD look at my answer if you want to skip to import multi libs..

Comment: @UWTDTV me too :))

Comment: @LAD you to what?

Comment: @UWTDTV I also prefer to using the same lib to make the code cleaner.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with BS, I just want to provide a solution.