# How to combine several similar commands using "for match in soup.find_all"?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have below code in which there are similar commands involved `for match in soup.find_all`. I would like to ask if it's possible to merge them and thus have cleaner code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/aimanter'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers = headers).content, 'html.parser')

entry_name = soup.h2.text

for script in soup.select('script, .hcdcrt, #ad_contentslot_1, #ad_contentslot_2'):
    script.extract()

for match in soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'copyright'}):  
    match.extract()
    
for match in soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'example-info'}):  
    match.extract()

for match in soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'share-overlay'}):  
    match.extract()
    
for match in soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'popup-overlay'}):  
    match.extract()    
    

content1 = ''.join(map(str, soup.select_one('.cB.cB-def.dictionary.biling').contents))
content2 = ''.join(map(str, soup.select_one('.cB.cB-e.dcCorpEx').contents))

format = open('aimer.html', 'w+', encoding = 'utf8')
format.write(entry_name + '\n' + str(content1) + str(content2) + '\n</>\n' )
format.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the various loops with `.find_all()` into the first `.select()`.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/aimanter'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers = headers).content, 'html.parser')

entry_name = soup.h2.text

for tag in soup.select('''
        script,
        .hcdcrt,
        #ad_contentslot_1,
        #ad_contentslot_2,
        div.copyright,
        div.example-info,
        div.share-overlay,
        div.popup-overlay'''):
    tag.extract()

content1 = ''.join(map(str, soup.select_one('.cB.cB-def.dictionary.biling').contents))
content2 = ''.join(map(str, soup.select_one('.cB.cB-e.dcCorpEx').contents))

format = open('aimer.html', 'w+', encoding = 'utf8')
format.write(entry_name + '\n' + str(content1) + str(content2) + '\n</>\n' )
format.close()
```

Comment: Your code works great and elegant to me. Could you please suggest some tutorial of  `BeautifulSoup` for beginners?

Comment: @LAD For sure the [official documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is first thing to read. But scraping is huge topic - CSS selectors and/or XPath, regex, json, HTTP... are things to learn (and they are not Python specific).

Comment: @AndrejKesely was faster then me but  i have almost an identical answer. To find great tuts you also can search youtube and do not listen on one single video..

Comment: @UWTDTV If you posted your answer, I would surely upvote it.

Comment: It would be a duplicate of @AndrejKesely answer. So i leave it like this.

Comment: Thank you so much @UWTDTV! Today you helped me solve several problems.

Comment: Could you please have a look at my [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63128493/how-to-combine-this-command-with-the-existing-one)?